# Are "<Dummy>" and "<Null>" keywords?

Tags: c++

```
static const string FindSentinel() { return "<Dummy>"; }
static const string Void() { return "<Null>"; }
```

What does this do, and how can these functions be used?

Comment: Those are functions which return certain string constants, inefficiently.

Comment: They are not keywords.

Comment: Those return `string` which should be a hint as to what those are returning.

Comment: Here is a list of all c++ [keywords](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword).

Answer (score 4):

```
Is "<Dummy>" and "<Null>" a keyword?
```

No. They are plain string literals.

The calling code *may* assign special meaning to those strings (if it wants to), but as far as the C++ *language* is concerned, they are just any old run-of-the-mill string literal - nothing to see here, move along.